# R table function including filtered out rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is read in with `readRDS()` as a df. This contains many rows with cities and states. I keep only data that is in the state of California as `df_ca`.

`df_ca` contains 100 columns and I only keep a few categorical columns. I create a new catagorical df called `df_cat`. I want to loop over the categorical columns and get the frequencies with the table function. Ignoring the loop for troubleshooting, I set var as `city` and execute the table function creating a new df called `cat_freq`. `cat_freq` contains all cities from `df` rather than `df_ca`, their Freq is 0. Why are they even showing up if they were filtered out? I am new to R but have a python background

```
df <- as.data.frame(readRDS('some.data.5140')) 
df_ca <- df[df$car.state == "ca",]
cat_col <- (unlist(list('color', 'city', 'deliver', 'type')))
df_cat <- df_ca[, cat_col]
var <- "city"
cat_freq <-  data.frame(table(df_cat[var]))
```

Comment: Look at `droplevels`.

Comment: doplevels did the trick - thank you!

Comment: Thomas: You can go ahead and accept your answer to show that the question has been resolved. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporating droplevels fixed the problem.

```
df <- as.data.frame(readRDS('some.data.5140')) 
df_ca <- df[df$car.state == "ca",]
cat_col <- (unlist(list('color', 'city', 'deliver', 'type')))
df_cat <- df_ca[, cat_col]
df_cat <- droplevels(df_cat)
var <- "city"
cat_freq <-  data.frame(table(df_cat[var]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is mostly because your columns are of type `factor` if you convert them to character it should help.

```
df_ca <- df[df$car.state == "ca",]
cat_col <- c('color', 'city', 'deliver', 'type')
df_cat <- df_ca[, cat_col]
#Convert all columns in df_cat to 
df_cat[] <- lapply(df_cat, as.character) character
var <- "city"
cat_freq <-  data.frame(table(df_cat[var]))
```